# Post processing isn't working after updating LWRP to URP

Tags: unity-game-engine

I updated the version of my [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) from 2019.2.9f1 to 2019.3.8f1.

I made the change from LWRP to URP and everything worked just fine except for the post processing. A new option appeared in the cameras (stacks) and a warning is displaying that says

> The render used by this camera doesn't support camera stacking

Only the base camera will render. Also, a new script is attached to the Main camera and cine machine camera "Universal Additional Camera Data". I'm using the two-dimensional renderer.

[image]

Comment: I was using postprocessing V2, that is not in use in the URP, just delete all things related to the ppV2 and created a new gameobject and put a Volume on it, not postprocessing volume, just volume, also check if your postprocessing is enabled in the main camera.

Answer (score 0):

**URP Post-processing**

1. Install the URP package via the package manager.

   (Post processing via the package manager does not install. It’s not necessary. URP does not support PPv2.)
2. Create Global Volume in hierarchy (example: create 3dobject → cube)

   - Right click → *Volume* → *Global volume*
   - Click on the new button (create volume profile)
   - Add override → post processing → add any effect.
     (Must be set in your URP rendering pipeline → *Post processing* → *Featured Set*: *Integrated*.)
3. How we can enable post processing

   - MainCamera → *Rendering* → *Post processing*. Tick in the check box.

   (It’s not necessary to add a post-processing layer component to the camera or VR camera.
   Please remove the post processing layer in the camera. It’s not supported in URP.)

Useful reference: *[Post-processing in the Universal Render Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/integration-with-post-processing.html)*